# how to remove "categories" title from the top of wp_list_categories(); output

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

I called my custom taxonomy category using **wp_list_categories();** Like this :

```
<?php 
$post_type = 'listing';
$taxonomy = 'listings_categories';
$orderby = 'ASC';
$show_count = 1;
$hide_empty     = 0;
$pad_counts     = 0;
$hierarchical           = 1;

$args = array(
          'post_type' => $post_type,
          'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
          'orderby'  => $orderby,
          'show_count' => $show_count,
          'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
          'pad_counts'  => $pad_counts,
          'hierarchical'   => $hierarchical
              );
?>

<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
```

So the output is like it : 
[image]

This is giving me •Categories just under Browse by Locations :

How to remove that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `'title_li' => '',` to your $args array.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_or_Hide_the_List_Heading

```
<?php 
$post_type = 'listing';
$taxonomy = 'listings_categories';
$orderby = 'ASC';
$show_count = 1;
$hide_empty     = 0;
$pad_counts     = 0;
$hierarchical           = 1;

$args = array(
          'post_type' => $post_type,
          'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
          'orderby'  => $orderby,
          'show_count' => $show_count,
          'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
          'pad_counts'  => $pad_counts,
          'hierarchical'   => $hierarchical,
          'title_li' => ''
              );
?>

<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: I've updated my comment with the complete code. I tried it on my own installation and it removed the "Categories" part as you requested.

Comment: Thanks, I understood now, i just putted my whole code into <ul> </ul> then it is in the same structure. Thanks. You are right.